# OPNsense won't forward ports from WAN to LAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, opnsense

I cannot get my xmpp client's ports to be forwarded from the WAN side of my FW to the LAN side chat server.

My configuration is:

```
Aliases:
xmpp_port=5222
xmpp_server=chat 

Firewall-->Port Forward

Interface: WAN
TCP/IP Version: IPV4
Protocol: TCP
Source: any
Source port range: any 
Destination: xmpp_server
Destination port range: xmpp_port
Redirect target: xmpp_server
Redirect target port: xmpp_port
Pool Options: Default
Nat reflection: Enable
Filter rule association: Rule
```

====
The #opnsense irc channel recommended I try:

```
Source port range: any
Destination: This Firewall
```

That didn't fix the problem.

1. Should I keep the irc suggested settings? I originally had `Source port range` set to `xmpp_port`.
2. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

I have done much searching on the internet and my config looks OK, so my hunch is that I have done something elsewhere that has messed up forwarding even though I do not have a complicated set up. Everything else seems to be functioning well.

Output from `ifconfig -a|grep inet` on my OPNsense firewall listed my LAN side gateway address among other addresses, none of which were my chat server.

Comment: Source port range = any is correct.  For Destination, do you have it set to the firewall's WAN address?  I don't know what "This Firewall" is, but if it is the LAN side gateway address, then that won't work.

Additionally, make sure that the rule is not after another rule that drops traffic or that sends traffic to some other host.

Comment: I  have added the ifconfig output to show the "This Firewall" IPs. It does list LAN side  gateway address. So I kept the Destination as xmpp_server.

Comment: Did you change Destination to "Wan Address"?  I think that is the problem.  Packets will arrive from the internet with your WAN address as the destination and with 5222 (xmpp_port) as the dest_port.  You need to match on that in order for the port forward to work.

Comment: Yes, I did. It still doesn't work. I have 5222 (xmpp_port) as my destination port.